# WARNING in ./node_modules/html2pdf.js/dist/html2pdf.js - Failed to parse source map

Tags: reactjs, source-maps, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf.js in my React project, and everything seems to be working fine. However, when I run the development server with react-scripts, I receive the following warning in the console:

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/html2pdf.js/dist/html2pdf.js
Module Warning (from ./node_modules/react-scripts/node_modules/source-map-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Failed to parse source map from 'D:\Projects\CRM Dev\crm_dev_repo\frontend\node_modules\html2pdf.js\dist\es6-promise.map' file: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'D:\Projects\CRM Dev\crm_dev_repo\frontend\node_modules\html2pdf.js\dist\es6-promise.map'
```

The warning references a missing file es6-promise.map. The PDF generation functionality itself works perfectly fine, but I want to address this warning to keep my project clean. Is there a way to fix this warning?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [html3pdf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html3pdf), which is a fork of the html2pdf.js library and shouldn't require any changes to your code.

html3pdf doesn't use the es6-promise library so it shouldn't throw that warning